# How should this Python code using "contextlib.nested" look in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from contextlib import contextmanager, nested
...

@documented_contextmanager
def _setenv(variables):
    if callable(variables):
        variables = variables()
    clean_revert = variables.pop('clean_revert', False)
    previous = {}
    new = []
    for key, value in variables.iteritems():
        if key in state.env:
            previous[key] = state.env[key]
        else:
            new.append(key)
        state.env[key] = value
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        if clean_revert:
            for key, value in variables.iteritems():
                if key in state.env and value == state.env[key]:
                    if key in previous:
                        state.env[key] = previous[key]
                    else:
                        del state.env[key]
        else:
            state.env.update(previous)
            for key in new:
                del state.env[key]

def settings(*args, **kwargs):
    managers = list(args)
    if kwargs:
        managers.append(_setenv(kwargs))
    return nested(*managers)
```

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/context_managers.py

As there is no `nested` in Python 3 - I need some help in converting it.
`2to3` just prints a lot of `Generating grammar tables from ...` but nothing useful.
How should this code look in Python 3?

Comment: You'd just use the `with manager1, manager2:` version of the statement directly instead of your wrapper function. `2to3` can probably only recognize the `with nested(manager1, manager2):` construct, not using `nested()` elsewhere.

Comment: What context is this `settings` function used in? All it is is a wrapper around `nested` that throws away keyword arguments. It looks like it's meant to plug into a specific role defined by some other API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to emulate `return nested(*managers)`:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack, contextmanager

@contextmanager
def settings(*args, **kwargs):
    # ... populate `managers`
    with ExitStack() as stack:
         yield tuple(stack.enter_context(cm) for cm in managers)
```

Comment: @Sergey: btw, `ExitStack` is available also in Python 2 in [`contextlib2`](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#contextlib2.ExitStack) if you want to use the same source on Python 2 and 3.